# Google Analytics data in Azure

Tags: azure, google-analytics, azure-blob-storage, apache-drill, presto

Has anybody ever moved Google Analytics data into Azure?  I have seen a handful of ways to do it but I am not sure what I am getting myself into.  The Google Analytics data is becoming quite large and I am wondering if it is best suited to leave it in google storage and access it from Azure or move it to something like HDInsight or Data Lake.  I need to join the data across several disparate data stores, SQL Azure, Blob, and Table Storage.  I was also looking into Apache Drill and Presto as a possible solution to unify the data access.  Just looking to see if anybody out there has dealt with this same issue and has any experience to share. Thanks!

Comment: This is best fit @ https://groups.google.com/group/presto-users

Answer (score 0):

## Preface

I don't have experience with Presto so I can only comment on the feasibility of doing this with Drill. Also I have not used Azure services so my advice is theoretical.

## Drill Storage Plugins

Drill will allow you to perform any SQL queries you want on data originating from different sources, provided that each data source has a storage plugin. A storage plugin is simply a piece of code in Drill that allows you to interface with a data source. Since you are concerned with performing queries on 3 data sources, we need to determine if each of those 3 data sources have a Storage plugin.

## SQL Azure

I assume SQL Azure has a jdbc driver for java. If so then Drill can be configured to use SQL Azure by following [these instructions](https://drill.apache.org/docs/rdbms-storage-plugin/).

## Azure Blob

Azure Blob storage has an implementation of the hadoop filesystem api which Drill uses to read data from file systems. So you could theoretically add the **hadoop-azure** jar and its dependencies https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-azure/2.7.0 to Drill's class path and configure Drill's DFS storage plugin to use it.

Additionally the data in Azure Blob would have to be stored in a supported file format like: json, parquet, csv, or hadoop sequence files.

## Azure Table

This looks like Microsoft's custom NoSQL database. Currently Drill does not support it.

## Conclusion

With a bit of work you could use Drill to query data on both Azure SQL and Blob, but not Azure Table.